# What has happened to this PHP CURL/SOAP script?

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, curl

I had a PHP script which was communicating with a third party API to send them order information using PHP CURL and SOAP. But now there is absolutely zero response from it. We changed servers a while back but my host has ran some tests to see the extensions are all working. Here's some code and debug:

```
            $ch = curl_init($this->apiUrl);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$this->xmlRequest");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $this->getCertificateXMLResponse = curl_exec($ch);  

            $aCURLinfo = curl_getInfo( $ch );
            print_r( $aCURLinfo );
```

The print_r produces this:

> Array ( [url] => https://www.theirdomain.com/theirdomain/Service/InsWebService.asmx [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.024002 [namelookup_time] => 0.001417 [connect_time] => 0.024017 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => XXX.249.XXX.218 [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => XX.174.XX.11 [local_port] => 44560 [redirect_url] => )

Does that not suggest they are not responding with anything or is it a problem my end?

My web host set up this test script to prove a point:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

$aCURLinfo = curl_getInfo( $ch );
      print_r( $aCURLinfo );


// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And out pops:

> Array ( [url] => http://www.example.com [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 322 [request_size] => 54 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.627453 [namelookup_time] => 0.429159 [connect_time] => 0.52812 [pretransfer_time] => 0.52816 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 1270 [speed_download] => 2024 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 1270 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.627415 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 93.184.216.119 [primary_port] => 80 [local_ip] => 79.174.170.11 [local_port] => 45182 [redirect_url] => )

So is it my code, my server, or the API's server acting up?

Comment: HTTP-code 0 usually means that you didn't even made the call. Do you have [PHP-cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) installed/compiled? Any error messages in the log?

Comment: Yes we do - and look what happened when we ran the code hitting example.com - we got: [http_code] => 200

Comment: debug this with verbose mode: [Php - Debugging Curl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456) - this can be for example an unsupported SSL mode. Also enable PHP error logging to the highest level and follow the PHP error log as well.

Comment: Is this my web hosts problem or their server from the debug? http://pastebin.com/CEzEHGmG

Answer (score 1):

OK I finally got my answer, suggested by my web host. SSL version needed setting, not automatically determining by PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Thank you to everyone who looked and helped.

Comment: next time consult CURLOPT_VERBOSE and curl_error() and curl_strerror() (-: